# Pass a struct to another class

Tags: c#

I have an array of structures in one C# class and I want to pass that data into another class.

Here is my code

```
private struct strClassOfService
{
    public string COS;
    public string myValue;
}

private strClassOfService[] arrCOS = null;

//
// some code that loads arrCOS with data
//

//
// here is where i will instantiate another class and
// set the arrCOS so I can use it in the other class
//
```

If all else fails I suppose I could reload the data in the other class. But I am curious if there is a way. So far my attempts have failed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how or why your attempts failed.  Show how you are trying to pass the array and use it in the other class.  From your post I can't tell if you are seeing compile time or runtime logic errors.

Comment: I was getting a compiler error. I don't remember the exact error but after doing some research I was able to pass it into a method of class B and load it that way. I don't know if that is the most effective way but I have a deadline of next week. Hopefully I will have time to explore it on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for one thing, if you intend to pass the structure to another class, you ought to make the structure definition public (or at least internal)... once you do that, you can use all sorts of methods (properties, method calls, etc) to copy the data over to your other class.

Two techniques are shown below (of course, you'd only need to use one...)

```
public class Foo1
{
    public struct Bar
    {
        string A;
        string B;
    }

    private Bar[] data;

    // Using a method
    public Bar[] ExportData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    // Using properties
    public Bar[] DataProperty
    {
        get { return data; }
    }
}

public class Foo2
{
    private Foo1.Bar[] data;

    // Using a method
    public void ImportData(Foo1 source)
    {
        this.data = source.ExportData();
    }

    // Using properties
    public Foo1.Bar[] DataProperty
    {
        get { return data; }
    }

    public void ReadProperty(Foo1 source)
    {
        this.DataProperty = source.DataProperty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make your struct `public`, you could consider declaring it `internal` instead: that way it's only accessible to other classes in the same assembly.